# Perpendicular distance from origin to the plane $x+2y+2z=6$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I am trying to find the perpendicular distance from origin to the plane $x+2y+2z=6$. I have an attempt at a solution, but it is incorrect, and I am hoping to find out why.

Consider the function $f(x,y,x)=x^2+y^2+z^2$. We'd like to minimize this function given the contraint $g(x,y,z)=x+2y+2z=6$. To do this, we use the Lagrange multiplier method.

We have $2x=\lambda, 2y=2\lambda, 2z=2\lambda$, from which we get $x=y/2=z/2$. Using this imformation, our constraint equation gives us $y/2+2y+2y=6$, which means that $y=z=4/3$ and $x=2/3$. Plugging this values into $f$, we get $(2/3)^2+(4/3)^2+(4/3)^2=4$.

The answer is supposed to be $2$, so I am not sure where I went wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe take squareroot, since your $f$ is the square of distance.

Comment: Of course, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Turning coffeemath’s comment into an answer since none of the others so far have really addressed your actual question.]

Everything was fine up until the end, when you apparently forgot that the function that you minimized gives you the *square* of the distance. Take the square root of the value that you’ve computed and all will be well.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Convert your equation into the Hessian Normalform:

$$\frac{x+2+2z-6}{\pm3}=0$$ Then the distance is given by $$\frac{6}{3}=2$$

Answer (score 0):

You have minimized the wrong function with the Lagrange Multiplier Method.

There is a well-known formula for the distance from a point to a plane.

The formula is  $$D= \frac {|ax_0+by_0+cz_0 -d|}{\sqrt {a^2+b^2+c^2}}$$

Where the point is $P= (x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and the equation of the plane is $$ ax+by+cz=d$$

With that formula we find the distance to be $$D=6/3 =2$$

Comment: So, which function should he have minimized?

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly what the OP did. How is that the “wrong” function, then?

Comment: @amd  The OP forgot to take the square root of his answer to get the actual distance.

Comment: @amd  The wrong function was too strong and I edited my answer. What I had in mind was that he minimized (correctly )  the square of the distance and forgot to take the square root at the end.